# Как отсортировать товар по рейтингу категории с сохранения id laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть таблица с товарами и таблица с категориями, у категорий есть рейтинг
Нужно отсортировать товар по рейтингу категорий
Вот, что у меня получилось:

```
$builder = Product::whereNotNull('title')
  ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT `id`, `rating` FROM `categories`)total'),
  function($join) {
    $join->on('category_id', '=', 'total.id');
  })
  ->orderBy('total.rating', 'DESC')
  ->paginate(10);
```

Все отлично сортируется, но встала проблема, что теряется id товара, т.к у обоих таблиц есть поле id
Возможно ли отсортировать без потери id товара?

Зачем мне нужен id товара?
На странице вывода товара есть кнопка редактирования товара, у меня редактирование товара происходит по такому урл /product/{id}/edit.
И теперь в id подставляется id категории
Знаю, что можно сделать вместо id - slug, что это делать 5 минут, но я хочу по id)

Comment: коли у вас джойн через raw-запрос, то и поименуйте там `select id as cId`

Comment: И укажите алиас таблицы для каждого поля - вот как раз чтобы было понятно, из какой таблицы взят тот или иной ID. `SELECT goods.id AS g_id, categories.id AS c_id, ...`